# Execute INSERT outside of a procedure using CASE WHEN

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I need to INSERT into `table_2` values coming from a `SELECT` result set, if and only if a specific column exists in `table_1`, then that column has to be dropped from `table_1`. Else nothing should happen.

Is it all about `DELIMITER`?
As far as I know, *no*, since code isn't part of a procedure declaration. I tried it anyway but it did not seem to help. It is getting tricky for such a tiny task to run.

My code so far, which triggers syntax errors warnings from Workbench:

```
CASE
-- MysqlWorkbench complains (CASE is underlined) saying …
-- «Syntax error: 'CASE (case) is not valid input at this position'»
WHEN EXISTS (
    SELECT * FROM information_schema.`COLUMNS`
    WHERE `TABLE_SCHEMA` = 'bd_name' 
        AND `TABLE_NAME` = 'table_1' 
        AND `COLUMN_NAME` = 'name'
    ) THEN
    INSERT INTO table_2 (caption,c_id)
        SELECT DISTINCT label, c_id FROM bd_name.table_1;
    ALTER TABLE table_1 DROP COLUMN label;
    -- I'm not sure about how should I separate statements
    -- regarding https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/case.html
END;
-- ("END" is underlined) Syntax error: extraneous input found - expected end of input
```

Thank you.

Comment: did you already try to use before insert trigger? As far as I know you can do this if exist then drop query.

Comment: No I didn't, I didn't even think of it at all, but I only need a one time execution snippet in the context of a table migration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think MySQL allows procedural constructs outside of routines, triggers, events, etc.... One way around this is to wrap your code in a proc declaration, and then follow it with a call to the proc and a drop of the proc.

Something like this:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE foo()
BEGIN
   Your stuff here;
   and here;
END$$

DELIMITER ;

CALL foo();
DROP PROCEDURE foo();
```

Comment: Okey, I will give it a try.